# Succulent plant for Hong Kong weather

Tags: succulents

As a sequel to my previous [question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4619/plant-which-can-withstand-heat-up-to-40-degree-celsius), I would like to seek genre of succulent plant which could withstand weather in Hong Kong, which is hot and damp in Summer.

Moreover, the place is usually around 35 degree Celsius in summer because of the heat released from the AC below.

I just bought a Hen and Chicks and a Haworthia but I doubt about their heat tolerance. Please suggest other genre but no cacti and Lithops.

Comment: Hens and chicks should do well in the heat, especially if it's damp. However, if you get an extreme amount of sun, you may want to shade them. I've found ours (in a northwestern USA area with hot dry summers) wither in it, in the summer, but they love the shade here then. I've never heard of them preferring shade in other areas, though. They do better with more water when there is all that sun than without it, though.

Answer (score 2):

Any gendre of cacti is good. They are plant from desert, then don't suffer from heat at all. Instead, suffer from dump. Maybe the wet clima is enough and you don't need to water them too much.

In desert regions they have a lot of rain with very high temperature in summer. Very cold and very dry in winter. So, if you want they give flowers, don't water them in winter at all.